# How to download file where application is stored?

Tags: c#, forms

So the following script is supposed to download a file to the location where the application is located. Now I Only can get GetTempPath to work. But that downloads file to the temporary folder. But I need it to download to the folder where the application is located.

```
var output = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.TempPath(), fileName);
```

And when I try different things instead of GetTempPath it states method not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

This will get the folder of the code of the currently executing assembly, basically the assembly which is executing your code.